# ffmpreg increased framerate when I tried to extract HEVC video to .hevc and .h265 extension

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

I tried to extract video track from the mp4 file. Here's the metadata for video track

```
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(pc, progressive), 3832x1600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 479:200], 29891 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
  vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Side data:
  DOVI configuration record: version: 1.0, profile: 5, level: 6, rpu flag: 1, el flag: 0, bl flag: 1, compatibility id: 0
```

and I used this command to extract video track

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.mp4 -c copy onlyvideo.h265
```

and the output file metadata for the video become like this

```
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(pc), 3832x1600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 479:200], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn
```

The framerate is increased and it made video shorter than the actual one.

This only happened when I extracted video to .h265 and .hevc extension, it fine when I used .mp4 or .mov but I need .h265 or .hevc to remux with Dolby Vision mp4 muxer tool. I also tried with Dolby's demuxer tool but It got the same problem (I think Dolby using ffmpreg to extract video too)

I already tried to fix framerate and set video timescale but non of these methods worked. Can anyone help me about this please? (Apologize for my bad English)

---

For the FFProbe output

myfile.mp4 duration

```
ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 -show_entries packet=pts_time,duration -read_intervals "%+#10" myfile.mp4

pts_time=0.000000
duration=1001
pts_time=0.166833
duration=1001
pts_time=0.083417
duration=1001
pts_time=0.041708
duration=1001
pts_time=0.125125
duration=1001
pts_time=0.333667
duration=1001
pts_time=0.250250
duration=1001
pts_time=0.208542
duration=1001
pts_time=0.291958
duration=1001
pts_time=0.458792
duration=1001
```

myfile.mp4 timebase

```
ffprobe -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -show_entries stream=time_base -select_streams v:0 myfile.mp4

1/24000|
```

onlyvideo.h265 duration

```
ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 -show_entries packet=pts_time,duration -read_intervals "%+#10" onlyvideo.h265

pts_time=N/A
duration=48000
pts_time=N/A
duration=48000
pts_time=N/A
duration=48000
pts_time=N/A
duration=48000
pts_time=N/A
duration=48000
pts_time=N/A
duration=48000
pts_time=N/A
duration=48000
pts_time=N/A
duration=48000
pts_time=N/A
duration=48000
pts_time=N/A
duration=48000
```

and onlyvideo.h265 timebase

```
ffprobe -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -show_entries stream=time_base -select_streams v:0 onlyvideo.h265
1/1200000
```

Comment: The reason for the difference is that MP4 gets the frame duration from the PTS timestamps. Raw H.265 video stream (without container) has no timestamps. The frame duration is determined by **packed duration** and the timebase. Please edit your post and add the output of FFprobe: `ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 -show_entries packet=pts_time,duration -read_intervals "%+#10" myfile.mp4` and also add the timebase: `ffprobe -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -show_entries stream=time_base -select_streams v:0 myfile.mp4`.

Comment: Do the same for `onlyvideo.h265`: `ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 -show_entries packet=pts_time,duration -read_intervals "%+#10" onlyvideo.h265` and `ffprobe -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -show_entries stream=time_base -select_streams v:0 onlyvideo.h265` (add the output to your question). Note that the reason may also be variable framerate (for that you have to analyze the timestamps of all the frames).

Comment: @Rotem I've added FFProbe duration and timebase output for both files. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I thought I had a good explanation for the issue, but I don't... You may try fixing the `h265` file using a [Bitstream Filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html): `ffmpeg -y -i onlyvideo.h265 -c copy -bsf:v hevc_metadata=tick_rate=24000/1001:num_ticks_poc_diff_one=1' onlyvideo_fix.h265`.